# Delete other users userfolder as administrator results in access denied

Tags: c#, windows, file-access

I wrote a tool which is supposed to delete userfolders of old users after some security checks.

The problem is although I start the application as administrator (with UAC to minimum settings) the application does not seem to have sufficient rights...

If I try to manually delete the folder in the explorer I get promted to do this as administrator and I click proceed ("fortsetzen" in my german version) and it works as expected, which prooves I/my login does have the neccesarry rights.

After some research I created a manifest and included this line in it:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

I also tried it with this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

same result: for the minority of userdirs it works, but the majority does not.

The function I use for deleting is:

```
DirectoryInfo userDir = new DirectoryInfo(usersDir + "\\" + user);
userDir.Delete(true);
```

These are the exceptions I get for two different users.

Original (for translation see below):

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Der Zugriff auf den Pfad "COPYING" wurde verweigert.
   bei System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   bei System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   bei System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Delete(Boolean recursive)
   bei LDAP_Search.Starter.deleteUser(String usersDir, String user)

System.IO.IOException: Der Zugriff auf den Pfad "C:\Users\lennartz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn" wurde verweigert.
   bei System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   bei System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   bei System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Delete(Boolean recursive)
   bei LDAP_Search.Starter.deleteUser(String usersDir, String user)
```

Translated by me:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The access to the path "COPYING" has been denied.
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Delete(Boolean recursive)
   at LDAP_Search.Starter.deleteUser(String usersDir, String user)

System.IO.IOException: The access to the path "C:\Users\lennartz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn" has been denied.
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Delete(Boolean recursive)
   at LDAP_Search.Starter.deleteUser(String usersDir, String user)
```

What do I need to do in order to make it work?
Shouldn't beeing administrator be enough?

EDIT:
Additional info (not shure if necessary):
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise successfully joined to a samba domain.
It's all domain users.
Userprofiles exist only locally.
I am member of a domain group called "edv" (german equivalent of "IT")
That group is added to the local administrator group of the client, where my application runs.

EDIT:
**Posted on superuser.com [here](https://superuser.com/questions/804183/delete-userdirs-as-administrator-access-denied)**

**Solved thanks to lzam on superuser.com**
Sollution:
I had to do the following things:

1. Take Ownership
2. Set Rights
3. Remove write protection flag
4. Delete it

Code:

```
SecurityIdentifier cu = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var fileS = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir.FullName);
fileS.SetOwner(cu);
fileS.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(cu, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(dir.FullName, fileS);
File.SetAttributes(dir.FullName, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

And for files:

```
SecurityIdentifier cu = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var fileS = File.GetAccessControl(dir.FullName);
fileS.SetOwner(cu);
fileS.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(cu, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
File.SetAccessControl(dir.FullName, fileS);
File.SetAttributes(dir.FullName, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

I had to do that for all files and directories recursively and was then able to delete them.

Comment: Think this is more something for http://superuser.com/ - it's probably not a programming problem.

Comment: Do you get the same results when you try to delete those files using the command prompt, at same security level as you run your program? If so then it's definitely not a programming problem but a systems problem.

Comment: Same problem with command prompt... Why does it work in the explorer then?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. When you have same problem with command prompt I definitely think you should post your question at the superuser.com site.